# Stored procedure throwing deadlock when my same instance is getting call by many users

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock

In SQL Server, I have written stored procedures, functions etc but I do not have good knowledge on locking and isolation.

I have this stored procedure where I did all my delete and insert with in `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN`.

Within `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN`, I am first deleting data from few tables and after that I insert data into those tables again with in cursor loop.

Basically from my C# application, I am sending big XML to the stored procedure and it loads that XML into a cursor and inserts the data into tables row by row. Now very recently I noticed that when I am calling this stored procedure, then I am getting deadlock errors frequently.

The deadlock occurs when my user using my application which on the other hand calling my stored procedure. I saw when approx 50 people are calling my stored procedure, then deadlock occurs.

Here is error screen shot:

[image]

Here is my stored procedure code which is long code but still I am posting here. Please see the code and tell me what I need to change in my stored procedure code to get rid of that deadlock. My database isolation level is the default isolation level.

My database version is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation 
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )
```

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_CRSSaveTickerBogey]                                                
     @TickerID VARCHAR(20),
     @UserID VARCHAR(20),
     @BogyXML XML,
     @LiConfigXML XML,
     @STATUS VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
 AS                                       
 BEGIN                                      
     DECLARE @XMLFormat AS INT, @SectionOrder AS INT                                                                
     DECLARE @Section VARCHAR(100), @LineItem VARCHAR(100), 
             @StandardDate VARCHAR(20), @StandardValue VARCHAR(20), 
             @XFundCode VARCHAR(20), @ActualProvidedByCompany VARCHAR(3)                                             
     DECLARE @MasterID INT, @SectionID INT, @LineItemID INT, @PeriodID INT, 
             @OrderID INT, @ConfigID INT                                       
                         
     DECLARE @TmpStandardFormula VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpStandardFormulaActual VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpBlueMatrix1stElementFormula VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpCrossCalc1Q VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpCrossCalc2Q VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpCrossCalc1H VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpCrossCalc3Q VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpCrossCalc4Q VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
             @TmpCrossCalc2H VARCHAR(MAX) = '',    
             @TmpCrossCalcFY VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
                          
     DECLARE @LI VARCHAR(100),
             @StandardFormula VARCHAR(MAX),
             @StandardFormulaActual VARCHAR(MAX),
             @AllowedDecimalPlace VARCHAR(5),
             @CurrencySign NVARCHAR(5),
             @CurrencyCode VARCHAR(10),
             @AllowPercentageSign VARCHAR(10),                          
  @AllowComma VARCHAR(5),                          
  @QCCheck VARCHAR(5),                          
  @QCType VARCHAR(10),                          
  @BlueMatrix1stElement VARCHAR(MAX),                           
  @BlueMatrix1stElementFormula VARCHAR(MAX),                          
  @DevelopmentStage VARCHAR(MAX),                          
  @CrossCalc1Q VARCHAR(MAX),                          
  @CrossCalc2Q VARCHAR(MAX),       
  @CrossCalc1H VARCHAR(MAX),     
  @CrossCalc3Q VARCHAR(MAX),                          
  @CrossCalc4Q VARCHAR(MAX),      
  @CrossCalc2H VARCHAR(MAX),     
  @CrossCalcFY VARCHAR(MAX),                      
  @SummaryTab VARCHAR(MAX)          
     
  SET @MasterID=0                                      
  SET @SectionID=0                                      
  SET @LineItemID=0                                      
  SET @PeriodID=0                                      
  SET @OrderID=0                                     
  SET @ConfigID=0                    
                         
  SET @Section=''                                      
  SET @LineItem=''                                      
  SET @StandardDate=''                                      
  SET @StandardValue=''                                      
  SET @XFundCode=''                                      
                                          
   SET @SectionOrder=1                  
                        
  BEGIN TRY                             
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;                        
   BEGIN TRAN                                      
                  
   BEGIN --Delete all ticker specific data first              
              
  --DELETE c          
  --FROM TblLineItemTemplate a INNER JOIN          
  --tblTicker_LiConfig c ON a.ID = c.LineItemID INNER JOIN          
  --tblSectionTemplate b ON c.SectionID = b.SectionID          
  --INNER JOIN tblCalenderMaster cm ON cm.ID=c.MasterID          
  --WHERE a.TickerID=@TickerID AND b.TickerID=@TickerID AND cm.TickerID=@TickerID          
          
 --Deleting data from tblTicker_Bogey          
  DELETE c              
  FROM TblLineItemTemplate a INNER JOIN              
  tblTicker_Bogey c ON a.ID = c.LineItemID INNER JOIN              
  tblSectionTemplate b ON c.SectionID = b.SectionID              
  WHERE a.TickerID=@TickerID AND b.TickerID=@TickerID              
                  
  SELECT @MasterID =ID  FROM tblCalenderMaster  WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID)              
  --Deleting data from tblTicker_LiConfig      
  DELETE FROM tblTicker_LiConfig WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID)         
          
  --Deleting data from tblSectionLineItemTemplate              
  DELETE c              
  FROM  TblLineItemTemplate a INNER JOIN              
  tblSectionLineItemTemplate c ON a.ID = c.LineItemID INNER JOIN              
  tblSectionTemplate b ON c.SectionID = b.SectionID              
  WHERE a.TickerID=@TickerID AND b.TickerID=@TickerID              
                  
  DELETE FROM TblLineItemTemplate WHERE TickerID=@TickerID              
  DELETE FROM tblSectionTemplate WHERE TickerID=@TickerID              
                  
  DELETE d              
  FROM tblCalenderDetail d INNER JOIN tblCalenderMaster M              
  ON D.MasterID=M.ID              
  WHERE M.TickerID=@TickerID              
                  
  DELETE FROM tblCalenderMaster WHERE TickerID=@TickerID              
  END              
                    
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblCalenderMaster WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID))                                            
   BEGIN                                            
    INSERT INTO tblCalenderMaster(TickerID,Following53Weeks,TransitionPeriod)                                                    
    VALUES(@TickerID,'N','N')                                                 
                                                
    SELECT @MasterID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()                                    
   END                                            
   ELSE                                            
   BEGIN                                            
    SELECT @MasterID = ID FROM tblCalenderMaster WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID)                                      
   END                                       
                                          
   --IF @MasterID > 0                                            
   --BEGIN                                            
   -- DELETE FROM tblCalenderDetail WHERE MasterID=@MasterID                                          
   -- DELETE FROM tblTicker_Bogey WHERE MasterID=@MasterID                                            
   --END                                
                                          
   --load xml data into cursor                                                    
   Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLFormat OUTPUT, @BogyXML                                       
                                          
   DECLARE CURRECORD                                                    
   CURSOR LOCAL FOR                                                    
   SELECT Section,LineItem,StandardDate,StandardValue,XFundCode,ActualProvidedByCompany                                                    
   FROM OPENXML (@XMLFORMAT, '/Root/PeriodicalData', 2)                                                    
   WITH                                           
   (                                                    
    Section   VARCHAR(100),                                                    
    LineItem  VARCHAR(100),                                                    
    StandardDate VARCHAR(20),                                                    
    StandardValue VARCHAR(20),                                                    
    XFundCode  VARCHAR(20),        
    ActualProvidedByCompany VARCHAR(3)        
   )                                       
                                          
   -- open cursor                                                    
   OPEN CURRECORD                                                    
   FETCH NEXT FROM CURRECORD INTO @Section,@LineItem,@StandardDate,@StandardValue,@XFundCode,@ActualProvidedByCompany                                                    
                                                        
   -- iterate in cursor to fetch value                                                    
   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)                                                    
   BEGIN                                                    
                                                      
   --REPLACE(TRIM(@LineItem),'''','''''')                          
   --CHR(39)                        
                              
   --PRINT @LineItem                        
                            
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TblLineItemTemplate WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID) AND TRIM(LineItem)=TRIM(@LineItem))                                 
    BEGIN         
     --IF once a xfund code inserted into TblLineItemTemplate table for a specific line item and if same xfund comes again for same line item
     --then prevent it from here to make duplicate xfund code
     --IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TblLineItemTemplate WHERE UPPER(TRIM(LineItem)) = UPPER(TRIM(@LineItem)) AND TickerID = @TickerID AND  XFundCode=@XFundCode)
     --BEGIN
     --    SET @XFundCode=''
     --END
            
     INSERT INTO TblLineItemTemplate(TickerID,LineItem,XFundCode,Action,UserID) VALUES (TRIM(@TickerID),TRIM(@LineItem),TRIM(@XFundCode),'I',@UserID)                                            
     SET @LineItemID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()                                               
    END                                            
    ELSE                                    
    BEGIN                                            
     SELECT @LineItemID=ID FROM TblLineItemTemplate WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID) AND TRIM(LineItem)=TRIM(@LineItem)                                            
    END                                        
                                          
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblSectionTemplate WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID) AND TRIM(Section)=TRIM(@Section))                                      
    BEGIN                                            
     INSERT INTO tblSectionTemplate(TickerID,Section,Active,OrderID)                                                    
     VALUES(TRIM(@TickerID),TRIM(@Section),'A',@SectionOrder)                                
                       
     SET @SectionOrder = @SectionOrder + 1                                 
                                                  
     -- storing identity value of last inserted item                                                    
     SELECT @SectionID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()                                            
    END                                            
    ELSE                                            
  BEGIN                                            
     SELECT @SectionID =SectionID  FROM tblSectionTemplate WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID) AND TRIM(Section)=TRIM(@Section)                                      
    END                                            
                                         
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblSectionLineItemTemplate WHERE SectionID=@SectionID AND LineItemID=@LineItemID)                                            
    BEGIN                                    
                      
   IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblSectionLineItemTemplate WHERE SectionID=@SectionID)                                            
   BEGIN                  
   SELECT @OrderID=MAX(OrderID)+1 FROM tblSectionLineItemTemplate WHERE SectionID=@SectionID                
   END                
   ELSE                
   BEGIN             
   SET @OrderID= 1                
   END                
                    
   INSERT INTO tblSectionLineItemTemplate(SectionID,LineItemID,Active,InsertDate,UserID,OrderID)                                                    
   VALUES(@SectionID,@LineItemID,'A',GetDate(),@UserID,@OrderID)                                                    
                                  
    END                                       
                                  
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblCalenderDetail WHERE MasterID=@MasterID AND TRIM(Period)=TRIM(@StandardDate))                                            
    BEGIN                                           
     INSERT INTO tblCalenderDetail(MasterID,Period,IsDeleted)                                                    
     VALUES(@MasterID,TRIM(@StandardDate),'N')                                          
                                          
     SELECT @PeriodID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()                                            
    END                                          
    ELSE                                          
    BEGIN                                          
     SELECT @PeriodID=ID FROM tblCalenderDetail WHERE MasterID=@MasterID AND TRIM(Period)=TRIM(@StandardDate)                                         
    END                                       
                                             
                                         
    --IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblTicker_Bogey WHERE MasterId=@MasterID AND SectionID=@SectionID AND LineItemID=@LineItemID AND PeriodID=@PeriodID)                                      
    --BEGIN                                      
     IF IIF(TRIM(@StandardValue) <> '',TRIM(@StandardValue),'') <> ''                                       
     BEGIN                                      
      INSERT INTO tblTicker_Bogey (MasterID,SectionID,LineItemID,PeriodID,[Values],UserID,InsertedOn,ModifyOn,status,ActualProvidedByCompany)                                      
      VALUES(@MasterID,@SectionID,@LineItemID,@PeriodID,TRIM(@StandardValue),@UserID,GetDate(),NULL,'I',@ActualProvidedByCompany)     
         
          PRINT 'Bogey Inserted'+CAST(@MasterID AS VARCHAR)               
    
     END                              
                                          
     --PRINT @Section+' '+ @LineItem+' '+ @StandardDate+' '+ IIF(@StandardValue<>'',@StandardValue,'No')                                      
     --PRINT CAST(@SectionID AS VARCHAR)+' '+ CAST(@LineItemID AS VARCHAR)+' '+ CAST(@PeriodID AS VARCHAR)+' '+ CAST(@SectionID AS VARCHAR)                                      
                                          
     --END                                      
                                          
    SET @SectionID=0                                      
    SET @LineItemID=0                                      
    SET @PeriodID=0                                      
    --SET @OrderID=0                      
                                          
    SET @Section=''                                      
    SET @LineItem=''                                      
    SET @StandardDate=''                                      
    SET @StandardValue=''                                      
    SET @XFundCode=''                                      
   FETCH NEXT FROM CURRECORD INTO @Section,@LineItem,@StandardDate,@StandardValue,@XFundCode,@ActualProvidedByCompany                                         
   END                                                    
                                                           
                                       
   CLOSE CURRECORD                                                    
   DEALLOCATE CURRECORD                                         
                     
   COMMIT TRAN                                      
                            
   SET @STATUS='SUCCESS'                             
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;                        
  END TRY                                      
  BEGIN CATCH                                                
   --PRINT 'err'                                             
    ROLLBACK TRAN                                                
                                                    
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);                     
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;                                                  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;                                                  
                                                    
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' occurred at Line_Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(50)),                                                  
     @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),                                                  
     @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();                                 
                               
     SET @STATUS='FAIL'                                              
     PRINT 'Err---> '+  @ErrorMessage                                         
     RAISERROR                           
     (                          
    @ErrorMessage, -- Message text.                                                  
    @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.                                                  
    @ErrorState -- State.                                                  
     );                               
   END CATCH                            
  END
```

The above code is not complete. I have cut down down before I pasted the code due to forum line constraint.

I set the **SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF** because data in my XML has single quote.

Please suggest to me a fix in my code as a result I should not get this deadlock.

Deadlock error is occurring when multiple user using my win application from where this above SP is getting called.

I am sure I am not getting error because of using Cursor. I am using SQL Server default isolation.

I am looking for suggestions on how to refactor my SP code such that deadlocks will not occur.

Comment: We need to see your deadlock graph to understand how the deadlock is happening. Also I advise you to do some reading up on deadlocks as they are fairly common and there isn't always a quick fix.

Comment: i am not database expert. so do not know how to acquire dead lock graph. dead lock not occurring often.

Comment: This is an advertisement for using [snapshot isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server#snapshot-isolation-level-extensions) which will increase memory and tempdb usage.  You could also use hints such as `WITH NOLOCK`, but they are hints.   And you can set the isolation level of the transaction itself.  Or refactor.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/save-deadlock-graphs-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15 for a guide on tracing deadlocks

Comment: Or alternatively, remove the deadlocks by ensuring one has the correct indexes, and order of table access.

Comment: should i use retry count logic like retry delete and insert in loop...if fail then retry again. so retry 5 times. would it be a good solution for my scenario?

Comment: Query and index tuning can help avoid deadlocks. Glancing at the queries, this `WHERE` clause cannot use an index on `TickerID` because of the `TRIM` function references column values (non-sargable expression): `WHERE TRIM(TickerID)=TRIM(@TickerID)`. The resulting full scan can contribute to deadlocks.

Comment: @DanGuzman Sir I have one request that if you have some time then please see my full code and point out those line and area which causing dead lock. thanks

Comment: An example scenario: 1) session one deletes `TblLineItemTemplate` rows, 2)  session two deletes different `TblLineItemTemplate` rows, 3) session one scans `TblLineItemTemplate` for non-sargable `IF EXISTS` subquery and is blocked by session two uncommitted delete, 4) session two scans `TblLineItemTemplate` for non-sargable `IF EXISTS` subquery and is blocked by session one uncommitted delete. Both sessions are waiting on each other, resulting in a deadlock. The solution may be to remove `TRIM` in the column values since the variable values are already trimmed during inserts.